# Stretching Iframe video past maximum screen width, can't find a way to hide the overflow

Tags: html, css, iframe, shopify

I have an Iframe I am pulling from Vimeo. I want to stretch it to a minimum width that's wider than the actual screen so that the height of the video fills a certain amount of it (ideally around 90% of the height of the page). If I keep the video at 100 vw, it's far too short on mobile.

My issue is that stretching the video past 100vw causes overflow to the right of the page without a way to hide it. overflow: hidden doesn't seem to work, and the only thing I could figure out to do is constrain the video to a max of 100vw, which isn't going to work either. Be forewarned, the code is a WIP and probably messy.

I've tried adding scrolling=no and setting overflow to hidden or none inline the Iframe, setting overflow to hidden on html body and universal selector, putting the iframe inside of another container which has a max width and overflow hidden, playing with height in css, and more.

Hopefully you guys can help!

```css
.vimeo-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.vimeo-wrapper-content {
  z-index: 2;

}

.vimeo-wrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hbtn {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 9px 38px;
  margin: 20px 9px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}



.hb-fill-right::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hb-fill-right:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}


.hb-fill-right:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: color 0.3s ease 0s, background 0s ease 0.3s;
}

.lfg-h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
  <div class="vimeo-wrapper-content">
    <span class="lfg-h1 lfg-ad-header">Business Name</span>
    <a href="#" class="hbtn hb-fill-right">Shop the Stuff</a>
    <a href="#" class="hbtn hb-fill-right">Watch More</a>
  </div>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/354737357?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: **overflow-x: hidden** applied to body should work. Look at this example https://codesandbox.io/embed/static-xsw95?fontsize=14

Comment: Amazing, I'll add this comment as answer then

Answer (score 1):

**overflow-x: hidden** applied to body should work. Look at this [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/static-xsw95?fontsize=14)